# Java JSoup Exception ignores try catch?

Tags: java, exception, try-catch, jsoup

I've got a program that uses JSoup to connect to and parse data from a website. When the website fails to connect after the 10 second timeout I've given it, the JSoup method throws an UncheckedIOException. This may contain an IOException like "SSL Peer shut down unexpectedly" or "timed out" which are IOExceptions I've dealt with in the past. It's weird because it wrapped in a try catch:

```
        Document document;
        try {
            document = Jsoup.connect("https://www.website.com").timeout(10000).maxBodySize(0).get();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return false;
        }
        Elements elements = document.select("tr");
        for (Element e : elements) {
            System.out.println(e.text());
        }
        return true;
```

I've done all sorts of workarounds like wrapping the method in a try catch, making the method throw exception and handling it higher up, and the above where I've isolated the line causing the issue and wrapped only that in a try catch. I've tried catching Exception, IOException, UncheckedIOException, etc but it all eventually still causes the whole application to crash due to the error seeping through somehow.

I've never encountered something like this. How is it that a try catch can't deal with the error? Is it the way JSoup has set up their error system? This can't be right, can it? I'm using JSoup 1.11.2 if that helps, downloaded from https://jsoup.org/download.

Comment: Can you also post the stack trace when your program crashes and indicate the code line numbers for us?

Comment: @luksch if it happens again I will, but it's quite rare, sometimes not happening once in a 24 hour period.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue was that an Error was not being caught because I was trying to catch an Exception. JSoup throws an Object that extends Error, not Exception, so when I did

```
try {

} catch (Exception e) {}
```

I should have done

```
try {

} catch (Error e) {}
```